# Google API Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

Tags: php, google-api, access-token, google-api-php-client

Working with the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) code, I found a problem: when the token needs to be refreshed, the code returns the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: refresh token must be passed in
>   or set as part of setAccessToken in
>   /app/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:258
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /app/gmail.php(32):
>   Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken(NULL)
>
> #1 /app/test.php(14): getClient()
>
> #2 {main} thrown in
>   /app/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php on line 258

I modified the `getClient()` function like this:

```
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URL);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);

    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } 
    else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        return printf("<a href='%s' target='_blank'>auth</a><br />", $authUrl);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    // ERROR HERE !!
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
```

After the first authentication (using the link created in the `getClient()` function), when the user lands to `REDIRECT_URL`, a `callbackAuth()` function is executed:

```
function callbackAuth() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URL);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);

    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authCode = trim($_GET['code']);

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    return $client;
}
```

I tried to apply the solutions of other related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314833/google-api-client-refresh-token-must-be-passed-in-or-set-as-part-of-setaccessto), but without results. Why does this error ocurr?

Comment: Do you confirm the token you "Load previously authorized credentials from a file." has the refresh token and the key is `refresh_token`? The error suggest it doesn't.

Comment: I checked the token and it only contains `access_token`, `token_type`, `expires_in` and `created` properties. How can I retrieve the `refresh_token` property?

Comment: The error doesn't say. Refer to the docs. How you get the access_token?

Comment: I get the access_token using a `callbackAuth()` function. Question was updated for more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Alex Blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110423/alex-blex) I was able to notice that the first time I receive the token has the `refresh_token` but after the first request, the `refresh_token` is not stored. The solution is the following ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105959/3549317)):

```
// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    $newAccessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $accessToken = array_merge($accessToken, $newAccessToken);
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
}
```

> The refresh_token is only returned on the first request. When you
>   refresh the access token a second time it returns everything except
>   the refresh_token and the file_put_contents removes the refresh_token
>   when this happens the second time.
>
> Modifying the code as following will merge in the original access
>   token with the new one. This way you will be able
>   to preserve your refresh_token for future requests.